# Why does this sh shebang not work?

Tags: bash, sh, shebang

In the following script (saved as `script.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $MY_PYTHON_WORKING_DIRECTORY
python script1.py
python script2.py
```

Then, when I try to run the command `script.sh` in my bash shell, I got the error `bash: script.sh: command not found`. Why does this not work as expected? If the first line of any scripts start by `#!` prefix, then the following path on the line is interpreted as a command, right? For your information, even if I changed my first line to `#!/bin/bash`, the same error still occurred. If I run the script as either `sh script.sh` or `bash script.sh`, then the script ran as expected.

Is there any way to run the script by just hitting `script.sh`?

One more question, between `sh` and `bash`, which should I use? I'm on OS X 10.8 and my default shell is currently set `bash`, but I wonder which one to use going forward.

Thanks.

Comment: You can execute it with `./script.sh`. It will check the first line to know which binary will execute it, in this case `/bin/sh`.

Comment: More than likely the script is not in a directory that is in $PATH.

Comment: When I executed it, I got a permission error. Then tried to run it with `sudo`, it still didn't work since `sudo` itself was interpreted as a command. So I changed permission in order to execute it without `sudo`, then the script worked. But do I have to change permission when I want to execute some files without specifying any commands?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, make the script executable:

```
chmod u+x script.sh
```

Second, your current directory is not in your $PATH. Therefore, you have to run the script with a path (relative is enough):

```
./script.sh
```